# Does grails validation not perform typechecking in Spock tests?

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I have a domain class defined in the following way:

```
import grails.mongodb.MongoEntity


class Testy implements MongoEntity<Testy> {

    List<Integer> ints = []
    Integer i

    static constraints = {
        ints nullable: false
    }
}
```

I discovered that validation doesn't check the types at all, so something like this is apparently fine:

```
class TestySpec extends Specification implements DomainUnitTest<Testy> {
    
    void "test something"() {
        given:
            domain.ints = ["1", "a", "hello"]
            domain.i = "a"
        expect:
            !domain.validate()  // The test fails -> validation is OK! How?
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering, is this supposed to happen? If so, why? And what can I do to enforce type checking?

**UPDATE: 2021-04-20**
So as per a comment by @Injecteer I tried this in my `TestyController` and there, validation seems to work properly. I'm unable to save a new instance from the following json, due to type errors:

```
{
    "ints": ["a"],
    "i": "1"
}
```

It seems like there is something wrong in my test.

**UPDATE 2: 2021-04-20**

I tried something different in my test, and apparently, when you directly set property values, it seems like typechecking is bypassed. So doing something like the following makes my test work as intended:

```
void "test something"() {
        given:
            // Set properties through constructor
            Testy testy = new Testy(ints: ["1", "a", "hello"], i: "a")  
        expect:
            !testy.validate()  // Validation fails -> test OK
    }
```

Comment: I think this should be handled by Groovy Type Checking and `domain.validate()` only validates the constraints.

Comment: is this happenning also in runtime? it smell with overmocking here

Comment: "I tried something different in my test, and apparently, when you directly set property values, it seems like typechecking is bypassed." - It is not the case that we bypass the typechecker but it is the case that when you do something like `domain.ints = ["1", "a", "hello"]` you are bypassing the Grails databainder and only default Groovy behavior is in place so type conversions, error handling etc. that would happen if you were using the data binder, won't happen.